# Limit SSH access by AWS security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-vpc, network-security-groups

I have two EC2 instances, both in the same public subnet and both in the same availability zone.

I want one of the instances to be able to access the other via SSH.

Here are the security groups I have configured so far:

**Instance #1: Web Server**

- allow_http `inbound and outbound port 80 0.0.0.0/0`
- allow_https `inbound and outbound port 443 0.0.0.0/0`
- allow_internal_ssh `inbound and outbound port 22 allow_internal_ssh (self)`

**Instance #2: SSH Only**

- allow_ssh `inbound and outbound port 22 0.0.0.0/0  # soon to be my home IP`
- allow_internal_ssh `inbound and outbound port 22 allow_internal_ssh (self)`

I want **#1** to only be accessible by SSH from **#2**.

I thought I could do that by assigning the same security group (`allow_internal_ssh`) to both, however, it's not working!

With the setup described above, I cannot connect to **#2**.

If I give both instances the `allow_ssh` security group I can access the SSH server **(#2)** and then from there login to the web server **(#1)**.

Any advice on debugging this or help to setup SSH access from the same security group would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your requirements are:

**Instance #1 (Web Server):**

- Allow HTTP/HTTPS access from anywhere
- Allow SSH only from Instance #2

**Instance #2:**

- Allow SSH access from your home

To accomplish this, you would need two security groups -- one associated with each instance.

You should create a **security group for Instance #1**:

- HTTP: allow inbound on port 80 from `0.0.0.0/0`
- HTTPS: allow inbound on port 443 from `0.0.0.0/0`
- SSH: allow inbound on port 22 from Security Group #2 (refer to the specific security group)

You should create a **security group for Instance #2**:

- SSH: allow inbound on port 22 from your home IP address

The magic is that one security group (#1) can refer to another security group (#2). In the above configuration, any instance associated with security group #2 would be allowed to access any instance associated with security group #1 on port 22. (Of course, standard login and keypairs would still be required.)

Comment: This is 100% the correct configuration.  And is actually what I had... the problem, in case, anyone else comes across this issue is that I was trying to SSH into the external IP of my server (therefore going outside of the VPC) once I configured my SSH connection to point to the private IP everything worked perfectly! Thanks for your help John

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow #2 to SSH into #1 you could allow inbound to the private IP address of #2 on port 22 (10.x.x.x)

Comment: Thanks @Rob I'll try that.  I tried to allow inbound from the private IP of #1 to #2 which didn't work... it DOES work with the public IP, but I'm trying to keep things within the VPC...

Comment: Are you sure they're both in the same VPC?  What are the private IP's for both servers? Also, I'm assuming you're trying to ssh into the private IP of server #1?

Comment: Thanks Rob the problem was **where** I was trying to SSH too... I was trying to connect to `my-server-1.mysubdomain.com` which was (of course) external and so the attempted connection was outside of the VPC.  I set up a private hosted zone and configured `my-server-1` to point to the private IP and job done!